# Check if string contains no characters except numbers?

Tags: php, validation

I need to check if a string contains NO other characters except numbers (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).

I'm expecting the user to input a time (12:00). I `explode()` the input to seperate the hours and minutes. I now need to make sure the time is an actual time value.

```
$time = explode(":",$time);

if ($time['0'] > 12 || $time['0'] < 1 || not_actual_numbers)
{
    //error: not valid hour
    echo("error: time val hour is bad");
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`is_int`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php)

```
$time = explode(":",$time);

if ($time['0'] > 12 || $time['0'] < 1 || !is_int($time[0]))
{
    //error: not valid hour
    echo("error: time val hour is bad");
}
```

Comment: Perfect I had over looked that function thinking it would see it as a string and say it's not an int.